# Can not control the second virtual machine

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I'm in a situation that have two virtual machines, the first machine use physical disk, the second is not. The problem is that the first VM require privileges to access the physical disk, I don't know if VMWare has problem with this, but after I started the first VM, I cannot control the second anymore (keyboard, mouse cannot enter in the second), It's seem to be not able to grab input. I don't see this before use physical disk, do you have any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Are you using the VMware client? When you connect to the second VM are you still connected to the first? Does the first VM have a virtual drive as well as access to the physical drive? Is the second VMs virtual drive file stored on the physical drive the first VM is accessing?

Comment: I'm using VMWare-Workstation, I start both VMs at the same time, the first VM use a physical disk(say disk 2), the first VM just a normal VM with file disk(on disk 1). They are independent and separate VMs, I think VMWare-Workstation console has problem with Windows UAC(because the first require UAC to start).

Comment: The first VM requires UAC to start because it's accessing a disk as a remote entity...but that still doesn't answer the question, does the file for the second VMs virtual image reside on the disk that the first VM is accessing? (OP posted this was not the case later)

Comment: So when you switch to the second VM in Workstation, is it still functioning normally, with the exception of not grabbing key and mouse activity?

Comment: that's right, and It can works normally right after I shutdown the first VM